# Why does array.splice() alter a variable, when used on a variable that is a copy of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Strings and arrays behave differently when altering a variable which was made from reference.

I'm curious why this is, as it confuses me greatly.

I was messing around with JavaScript, and noticed something that I don't fully understand.

Let's say I make a variable.
`var a = 'Hello';`

Then I make a new variable by reference to the "a" variable.
`var b = a;`

Now I alter the b variable.
`b = 'World';`

The "a" variable remains "Hello".
`console.log( a ) // 'Hello'`

However, if I make the "a" variable an array, and once again reference it in the "b" variable, now altering the "b" variable also alters the "a" variable.

```
var a = [ 'Hey', 'There', 'Buddy' ];
var b = a;

b[1] = 'Where?';

console.log( a ) // [ 'Hey', 'Where?', 'Buddy']
```

Why do arrays behave differently from strings and other data types in shown example?

Comment: `Array.splice` alters/mutates the *object*. The variable *names* the object. Assigning of variables simply assigns an alternative *name*.

Comment: On Javascript, primitive types are copied by values, while objects (array is an object), are always passed by "copy of reference".

Comment: I can't decide which duplicate to vote this as a duplicate of :)

Comment: @Shidersz *Everything* in JavaScript is passed by value (better classified as Call by [Object] Sharing in this particular case).. the crucial difference between 'primitive' and 'object' in this case is really the difference between *immutable* and *mutable*. If the object was *immutable* then there is no effective difference.

Comment: Another `tip`: if you want to create a new copy of the array, you can use `var b = a.slice(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do arrays behave differently from strings and other data types in
>   shown example?

This is because string in javascript are passed by value or copied and not reference. Whereas arrays are passed by reference.

Suppose you have:

```
 var a = "Hello":
 var b = a;
```

The value of variable `a` is been copied to variable `b`.

But when you do :

```
var a = [ 'Hey', 'There', 'Buddy' ];
var b = a;
```

You just pass reference of the array a to b. So both a and b points to the same reference. Therefore changes made in any one of them will reflect in other.

Basically you have something in the memory as:

```
a:ref12344−−−+
             |
             |
             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 
             +−−−>|  Array      |                 
             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 
             |    | String      |         
             |    | String      |
b :ref12345−−+    |             |       
                  |             |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: I selected this as the answer, because it was best explained and illustrated in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

Because b is not a copy, it's a pointer. The array is the same (there is only one instance of it).

One of the way to do a copy of an array is too slice it fully (from its first element at index 0).

```
var b = a.slice(0);
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: There are no pointers (or even references [excluding the reference specification type]) in the ECMAScript definition :}

Comment: @AsTeR is correct. **Underneath** the code Arrays are passed around as pointers. So, in their example both `a` and `b` point to the same set of data which is why changing `b[0]` also changes `a[0]`/

Comment: @user2864740 hum ... ok. How are they called in the JS lingo?

Comment: @AsTeR 'objects'? :) Mutating an object affects that object; if no *copy/clone* of the object is made, then .. it's the same object.

Comment: Quite the contrary: In JavaScript / ECMAScript, an assignment (including assignment to function parameters) **does not** make a copy/clone of an object. Therefor, if that object is mutated, the *same **not** copied/cloned* object is mutated because.. it's the *same object*.. everywhere. This is the basis of [Call by (Object) Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). (As primitive types are immutable this same logic can be extended to primitive values without general observable effect; if there is a 'copy' made it is an implementation detail only.)

Answer (score 1):

They behave different, because a `String` is referenced by value. The `Array` on the other hand, is a reference by pointer and as such "mirrors" modifications on either of the variables.

If you want to generate a clone of the array, do it by creating a new array:

```
var old = [1, 2, 3];
var ref = old;       // <-- ref still points to "old"
var copy = [...old]; // <-- not a reference any longer
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just pointing to a reference of the array.  `var b` isn't "holding" the array, but it is pointing to where the array was initialized, which is still `var a`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript is passed by value for the primitive types (Number, string ecc...) but it changes when you touch an object (the same for array) it is passed by referece.

```js
var a = 2;
var b = a;
b = b - 1;
console.log(a,b)

var c = {
  a: 2
  }
var d = c;
d.a = d.a -1;
console.log(c, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, **arrays** and **objects** are **reference types**. This means that when a variable is assigned an array or object, what gets assigned to the variable is a reference to the location in memory where the array or object was stored, and not the content of the object/array itself.

However, contrary to some languages, strings are **value types** in JS and not arrays, they behave just like number, boolean, null and undefined when assigned and copied.

The `splice` method does not generates a new array, it **mutates** the array given asargument, so every other variable referencing this same array will also see the change.

If you want your source array to stay unmodifed, use the `slice` method instead, which is **immutable**. It will make a copy, mutate this copy and return it.